# Save XML file from rails template

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

The following generates an XML file of users:

```
def index
  @user = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml
  end
end
```

How can I save that same XML file to the server side?

Technical Note: I'm using jRuby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the XML string with the `to_xml` method:

```
xml_string = @user.to_xml
```

Use the Ruby `File` class to save the file in whatever directory you want it.  Here is the general syntax:

```
File.open(local_filename, 'w') { |f| f.write(xml_string) }
```

To save the file in the `/tmp` directory, just use this:

```
File.open(Rails.root + "/tmp/my_file.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(xml_string) }
```

If you want to save the file when the `index` action is run, just put it in the `index` action.

Comment: But how do I get the "xml_string" from xml template? I have index.xml.erb. The result of that template needs to be written to the "xml_string" variable

Comment: @dremme - I updated the answer.  The `to_xml` method can be used to convert a single object or a collection of objects to XML.  Since the `@user` instance variable represents a collection of users, you may want to rename the variable `@users`.  Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This makes sense. A little different than my first approach, but this works too. Thanks.